# Convert Facebook Graph API Date to UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, facebook

How might I convert a Facebook Graph API Date to a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: What is the date format? Can you not just use `strtotime()`?

Comment: It's: 2012-04-24T22:01:00+0000 Didn't tried strtotime() as i've read it's a bit unsafe, sometimes fails...

Comment: This is basically ISO 8601 and seems to work fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the date format but I suspect it is in a common and/or standard format so [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should work just fine.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-04-24T22:01:00+0000');
```

Answer (score 16):

Facebook recently added a feature where date/times will be returned in Unix timestamp format, simply add the `date_format=U` query parameter to end of your Graph call. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?date_format=U&access_token=.....
```

This will return time/dates in Unix timestamp format (such as 1309572000).

> Note: As of now only the updated_time in timestamp format but not the start_time

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was struggling with datetime and timezone. This helped.