# Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 when i try to read pictures from facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to reading the pictures from my Facebook albums.

This is the code that I use for reading the albums:

```
- (void)storePhotoIntoCoreDataFromAlbumId:(NSString *)albumId whitAlbumName:(NSString *)albumName
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos",albumId];
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:request
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                  if (!error) {
                                      if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                                          if ([[result valueForKeyPath:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                                              NSString *firstPageToRead = [result valueForKeyPath:@"paging.next"];
                                              [self storePicture:[result valueForKey:@"data"] withAlbumTitle:albumName];
                                              if (firstPageToRead) {
                                                  [self pagingQueryUntil:firstPageToRead];
                                              }

                                          }
                                      }
                                  } else {
                                      NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error);
                                  }
                              }
         ];
    }
}
```

This code works great, the problem it's inside the `[pagingQueryUntil:firstPageToRead]` method.
I use this method in case there are a lot of pictures in the same album and I can't read it in one shot.

In this method I'm going to connect to the page to read the pictures in it:

```
- (void)pagingQueryUntil:(NSString *)until {
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            until, @"until",
                            nil];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
 NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error);

}
```

And I got this error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xd092be0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0xd089520, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 581914168536264, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xd1b0960>, expirationDate: 2014-07-19 08:35:28 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-20 08:36:52 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "basic_info",
    "user_photos",
    installed,
    "user_location",
    "public_profile",
    email,
    "user_birthday",
    "user_friends",
    "friends_photos"
)>}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What are you passing as a value to `pagingQueryUntil`?

Comment: i pass and url like this: https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/10151580856822785/photos?access_token=CAAIRP3NOLMgBAOVeH8BjHqL2jh35auCZCKUdUt1hRpZCKohLaZCDJYcIcJGsEyxe4LK5gLowKrwIZAMCpd5MTtsVjUt8R.... if i open the url i got a list of pictures, so i think the url it's right

Comment: So, your variable `until` is "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/10151580856822785/photos?access_token=CAAIRP3NOLMgBAOVeH8BjHqL2jh35auCZCKUdUt1hRpZCKohLaZCDJYcIcJGsEyxe4LK5gLowKrwIZAMCpd5MTtsVjUt8R"? If that's the case then that's your problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture that the string you are passing to `pagingQueryUntil` does not conform to one of the supported date and time formats outlined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). Because of this, the API is returning the error you see:

```
message = "(#100) Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()";
```

Comment: i tried to add 'date_format=U' like it's written in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417868/convert-facebook-graph-api-date-to-unix-timestamp but i got the same error!

Comment: Log out the value of `until`. That value should conform to the date and time formats. If it doesn't then that's your problem.